# How to use move semantics for std::vector member without breaking encapsulation?

Tags: c++, vector, move, encapsulation

Let's suppose that I have a class with a private std::vector member, and the class maintains some contract on the content of the vector, e.g., keeps elements sorted.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
  using value_type = std::pair<int, float>;

  Foo() = default;

  explicit Foo(const std::vector<value_type>& data):
    data_(data)
  {
    std::stable_sort(data_.begin(), data_.end(), [](const value_type& lhs, const value_type& rhs)
      {
        return lhs.first < rhs.first;
      });
  }

  explicit Foo(std::vector<value_type>&& data):
    data_(std::move(data))
  {
    std::stable_sort(data_.begin(), data_.end(), [](const value_type& lhs, const value_type& rhs)
      {
        return lhs.first < rhs.first;
      });
  }

  // Return the element corresponding to the given key,
  // 0 if there is no such element
  float getValue(int key) const
  {
    auto cmp = [](const value_type& element, int key)
    {
      return element.first < key;
    };
    auto it = std::lower_bound(data_.begin(), data_.end(), key, cmp);
    if (it == data_.end() || it->first != key)
    {
      return 0;
    }
    return it->second;
  }

  // Increment all keys by the specified value
  void incrementAllKeys(int value)
  {
    for (value_type& element : data_)
    {
      element.first += value;
    }
  }

  // Add an element.
  // Internal vector remains sorted.
  // O(N) complexity in the worst case (adding an element to front),
  // because data has to be moved.
  void addElement(int index, float value);

private:
  std::vector<value_type> data_;
};
```

All member functions maintain the class contract (data_ is sorted). However, the user still has a way to
break the contract when moving data into Foo:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, float>> v
{
  {10, 1.4322f},
  {1, 3.223f},
  {5, 2.2323}
};
// Get a pointer to actual data
std::pair<int, float>* ptr = v.data();

Foo foo {std::move(data)}; // OK, the constructor sorts data

// Legal: ptr is not invalidated after move/sort
assert(ptr[0].first == 1);
// Break the internal state
ptr[0].first = 42;
```

I want to ensure that the user won't be able to modify Foo::data_. Of course, I can simply forbid moving data into Foo, but this is undesired due to performance (redundant copying).

This issue is not limited to std::vector: this applies to any container, for which pointers/references and/or iterators are not invalidated after move.

I considered using the Builder pattern, e.g.:

```
class FooBuilder
{
public:
  void reserve(std::size_t capacity);
  void addElement(int key, float value);

  // Moves data into Foo.
  // This class has to be a friend of Foo;
  // alternatively, Foo can be constructible from FooBuilder and FooBuilder should have some
  //   std::vector<std::pair<int, float>> FooBuilder::release();
  // member function.
  Foo build();

private:
  std::vector<std::pair<int, float>> data_;
};
```

FooBuilder solves the exposure problem, while allowing move semantics, but its public interface is very limited compared to std::vector.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: If users of your class wants to break encapsulation it's their responsibility, and if something goes wrong it's their problem. You can very seldom protect yourself 100%.

Comment: You simly specify in te documentation 
that pointers and references might be invalidated. (Or simply don't promise they are not). From that point on, if the user touches moved-in data, it's UB and their respinsibility.

Comment: This is why `map` declares the key type to be `const`.

Comment: @NicolBolas it wouldn't help in this case though.